# Microsoft edge auto changes efficiency mode for sub processes

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I have disabled efficiency mode on ms edge on windows 11 22h2. But some sub processes still have efficiency mode as i see in task manager. I go to the process details and set its priority from low to normal but after a few minutes it again becomes low priority and efficiency mode.

I want to permanently set normal priority and disable efficiency mode for all processes of MS edge